# Product display and taxonomy term ID filter (with depth)

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, commerce

I have a view for nodes that show my products by product reference field.
All of these products tagged with "Catalog" vocabulary. 
I have added a reference to the field_product in the view.

Is there any way to use contextual filter «**has taxonomy term ID (with depth)**» for this view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment there is no easy/correct way of doing things as far as I know.

You could try to:

use [Commerce Taxonomy Reference](https://drupal.org/sandbox/yanniboi/1462604) (sandbox project). Excerpt from the page:

> If you want to add the Contextual Filter 'has taxonomy term ID (with
>   depth) to a Commerce Product View this module will accomplish that.

This does what you need, but I can't get it to work: there are some versions mismatching etc.

**OR**

You could move the Taxonomy Reference field away from the Commerce Product to the Product Display node (content type) and use the normal filter (Content: has taxonomy term ID (with depth)).

Answer (score 1):

- Clone the default view called "taxonomy term" and start from there.
- Add a relationship to your product, and save.
- Add fields as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Taxonomy Entity Index](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_entity_index) module

This creates a more complete taxonomy index for all entity types, and provides useful Views filters.

Note: if installing on a site with existing content, you need to rebuild the index from the Configuration page before it'll work.